# How to unit test a class to check it can be used in a Set or Map (i.e. contains always works)

Tags: java, scala, unit-testing, set, contains

I discovered that some instance of a (java) class that I used in Maps and Sets sometimes fails to be found using the `contains` method.

The problem was *simply* that the class did not implement "hashCode" (but it has `equals`). And the subtlety was that it actually works most of the time: I only found out about the error when running some code with concurrency.

My problem now is that I'd like to make a unit test that assert that this class can be used reliably in a Set/Map (i.e that `.contains` works) but I cannot reproduce the bug.

As I say, almost all the time it actually works. I tried to make a Set of a couple of instances, then run multiple times `contains` with copies of these instances, in parallel. But it always works.

What test of `mySet.contains(item-copy)` would fails for sure if item class has not `hashCode`?

Here is the test pseudo code that don't fails when `MyItem` does not implements hashCode:

```
def testFindInSet(): Unit ={
  val items = Seq(---list of args---).map( args => new MyItem(args)}.toSet
  items.par.foreach{ item =>
    (1 to 100).par.foreach{ k =>
      val itemCopy = new MyItem(item)  // that's a copy constructor
      assertTrue("item not found", items.contains(itemCopy))
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried to make a Set of a couple of instances

Scala has [specialized representations](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/d6728ce984f80c43a41615e6aa590b5a3d483bee/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Set.scala#L67-L218) for sets up to 4 elements instead of using `HashSet`. I expect making a larger set or using `HashSet` explicitly should be enough to make it fail. But it's simpler just to compare `hashCode` of copies: `assertTrue("hashCode not implemented", itemCopy.hashCode == item.hashCode)`. If this fails, the contract is already broken (assuming `itemCopy == item`).

Comment: That's it. I tested with more that 4 items as well as with HashMap if less than 4 items and the bug is reproduced. tricky one